проксирование трафика v2ray
Имеетсяс подписка на прокси по протоколу vless. серверы подгружаются по ссылке на эту подписку.
Имеется клиент v2ray который на андроиде работает идеально.
Имеется debian12.
v2ray и v2raya установлены в автоматическом режиме
git clone https://github.com/leohab75/install_v2raya.git && cd install_v2raya/ && bash install_v2ray

Сам софт работает но проксировать трафик либо не хочет.
На вебморде v2raya импортирую ссылку на серверы, в настройках вебморды включаю прокси всего кроме китайских сайтов. Выбираю сервер из доступных по подписке и нажимаю run.
Но при попытке зайти на како-нибудь сайт выдает ошибку
An error occurred during a connection to www.google.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Отключаюсь от сервера и сразу все работает. Серверы точно рабочие. Нужно видмо как то еще дополнительно конфигурировать debian но как?
Подскажите пожалуйста
